# Turning a file into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def read_database(file):
    d={}
    file=open('database.txt')
    for line in file:
        (key,val)=line.split(';')
        d[key]=val
    return d

print(read_database('database.txt'))
```

This code returns

```
{'GGGGGCTACAAACTCTCAGG': 'High blood pressure,Osteoarthritis,liver disease\n', 'AGCTCAGTATAAAATCTAAG': 'Diabetes,lung disease\n', 'AAAAATCTATGCTCACCGAC': 'Breathing problems\n',...}
```

but I want to get rid of the "\n" at the end of each line. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: `d[key]=val.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_database(filename):
    d = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            key, value = line.split(';')
            d[key] = value
    return d

print(read_database('database.txt'))
```

I fixed some other issue, while at it

- You pass in something as 'file', just to immediately overwrite it
- File is not closed
- Not following PEP8 whitespace recommendations